# Why is valid code causing c# to fail

Tags: c#, jquery, razor

I have a jquery post calling a cshtml page which works.  Some server-side code is happy and some code simply isn't accepted.  e.g.

```
@{
    string input;
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream)){
    input = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

From:  http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/220/posting-data-with-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-razor-web-pages

Works *\o/*

However:

```
@{
    string input;
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        input = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

   try
   {
     //do something doe not work.... whole cshtml page fails
   }
}
```

Comment: Post the actual code from your `try` block.  There is obviously something that is *not valid* that is causing your page to not load.

Comment: Oddly if I don't use try I can create a ManagementObjectCollection but as soon as I add foreach (ManagementObject object in Collection){} the whole thing fails as well....  it very frustrating as this code works normally....

Comment: e.g. foreach (ManagementObject vm in VirtualMachines) { }
fails in or out of try.

Comment: ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + VMHost + @"\root\virtualization\v2", null);
    string q = "select * from Msvm_ComputerSystem Where Caption like '%Virtual Machine%' and Name like '%" + @VM + "%'";
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery(q));
    ManagementObjectCollection VirtualMachines = searcher.Get();


    var VMCount = VirtualMachines.Count;
    VirtualMachines.GetType();

GetType shows it's a ManagementObject

Comment: @MarkPerry you're better off editing the question and adding the code there. In the comments it is hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for the notice guys...
grr turns out after bloody hours it's Razor syntax that gets me!!!

In code blocks its mostly not a good idea I've noticed as it was breaking @VM should have been VM.  However I do still need it on occasion e.g. for posted variables.

Answer (score 0):

I foolishly fell over an issue with the razor syntax breaking my braces {}.  Id used @ in from of a c# variable which wasn't needed.